# Search XPath using variables, issue with single quotes

Tags: php, xml, xpath

This seems to be the correct syntax for using XPath with variables:

```
$color = "green";
$list = $xml->xpath("/A/B/C[@COLOR = '$color']/D");
```

and so on, where the variable appears within single quotes. However, some of my data contains apostrophes, causing the following code to return no results:

```
$word = "can't";
$list = $xml->xpath("/A/B[@CATEGORY='$word']/C/D");
```

Anytime the variable value an apostrophe, this query doesn't work. I have tested this by removing apostrophes from the data and it works fine. Is there a way around this? It is not feasible for me to permanently remove all apostrophes from the data, and some values may differ only in an apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a small chance that your variable would contain double quotes, then reverse the double with singles like:

```
$word = "can't";
$list = $xml->xpath('/A/B[@CATEGORY="'.$word.'"]/C/D');
```

If you also have double quotes then you need to escape your quote/double quote, replace `'` with `\'` and keep it the way it is.I think you can use `strpos`.